# Android and JUnit: How to add individual tests to test suite?

Tags: android, junit

I've been struggling for a while with this. When creating a test suite in JUnit/Android, I can to the following:

- Add all the tests (in all the classes) that exist in the same package as the suite
- Add a specific class contatining testMethods

However, I'm completely unable to do the following:

- Add a specific testMethod from a specific class to the test suite.

Now, I understand that this SHOULD be possible, as there are countless examples showing this.

This is how it's supposed to work:

The test class contatining the test methods:

```
import com.frank.android.lookup.SomeClass;
import android.test.AndroidTestCase;

public class ArithmeticsTests extends AndroidTestCase {
    SomeClass sctest;

    protected void setUp () throws Exception {
        sctest = new SomeClass();
        super.setUp();
    }

    public void testAddNumbers () {
        assertEquals(9, sctest.addNumbers(3, 6));
    }

    public void testSubtractNumbers () {
        assertEquals(2, sctest.subtractNumbers(6, 4));
    }

    protected void tearDown () throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }
}
```

And here's the test suite class:

```
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class ProjectTestSuite_SomeTests extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite () {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("ArithmeticsTests");
        suite.addTest(new ArithmeticsTests("testAddNumbers"));
        suite.addTest(new ArithmeticsTests2("testSubtractNumbers"));

        return suite;
    }
}
```

Now, the two lines where I try adding the individual test methods result in this error:

```
The constructor ArithmeticsTests(String) is undefined
```

Now, I've looke around for a long time, and I cannot find any explanation for this. It seems that something is missing, since it doesn't understand what I'm trying to do. The "string" it complains about is in fact the name of the method - I'm not trying to pass a string to a constructor of the class - I'm trying to add the method of the class to the test suite.

I'm using the JUnit version that's included with the Android SDK here, and I haven't installed anything else related to that. Is there something missing? (Obviously there is, bit what?)

### EDIT:

I added a construtor to the ArithmeticsTests class:

```
public ArithmeticsTests (String s) {}
```

Now the above error is gone.

However, when I run the test suite, I get this error:

```
testSuiteCreationFailed
....
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Method name must not be null.
```

Comment: Well, it's obvious: you don't have an `ArithmeticsTests(String)` constructor.

Comment: It seems to be obvious, yes. So I added a constructor "public ArithmeticsTests (String s)" to the test class. No error messages in the editor, but when I run the test suite I get this error: testSuiteConstructionFailed. See updated main post.

Comment: Could you link to some of these "countless examples"?

Comment: F.ex. the Android API documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/junit/framework/TestSuite.html

Comment: Fantastic. It seems that 1. No one has ever seen this problem, and 2. No one has any clue about it.

Comment: Did the answer below work for you ? If not please comment on it - if yes please accept

Comment: And how is this question different than the other one --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14234131/how-do-i-create-android-test-suite-which-only-runs-specified-tests-in-one-or-mor?

Comment: Nope. None of the answers solved it, and I don't expect anyone to be able to either. So I really cannot accept any answer here.

Comment: @kakemonsteret  Out of curiosity, why did you choose to use TestSuite & AndroidTestCase instead of ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 or ActivityUnitTestCase classes?

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the same problem and discovered that, while `AndroidTestCase` does not have a constructor taking a `String` parameter, it does have a `setName(String name)` method. By calling the `setName` method, you can add individual method to the test case.
Using the code in your example, your test suite may look like:

```
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class ProjectTestSuite_SomeTests extends TestSuite {

    public static Test suite () {
        TestSuite suite = new TestSuite("ArithmeticsTests");
        ArithmeticsTests arithmeticsTests = new ArithmeticsTests();
        arithmeticsTests.setName("testAddNumbers");
        suite.addTest(arithmeticsTests);
        ArithmeticsTests2 arithmeticsTest2 = new ArithmeticsTests2();
        arithmeticsTest2.setName("testSubtractNumbers");
        suite.addTest(arithmeticsTest2);

        return suite;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
public static TestSuite suite() {
    final TestSuite t = new TestSuite();
    t.addTest(TestSuite.createTest(TestExampleClass1.class, "test1"));
    t.addTest(TestSuite.createTest(TestExampleClass2.class, "test2"));
    t.addTest(TestSuite.createTest(TestExampleClass3.class, "test2"));

    return t;
}
```